# D3.js linechart - controlling x-axis with dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

I have created a linechart with D3.js, but can't seem to figure out how to control the X-axis completely.

You can see my example her: http://codepen.io/DesignMonkey/pen/KdOZNQ

I have sat the ticks count for the x-axis to 3 days, and I have an Array with a range of 31 days, that should show a day in each end of the x-axis and skip to every third day. But for some reason when the a-axis pass the 1st in the month, it shows both 2015-08-31 and 2015-09-01 and doesn't skip to 2015-09-03 as it is supposed to.

My code for the linechart is here:

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
let margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 330 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 180 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).nice(10);
var y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 3)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%e'))
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10)

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10)

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

// Adds the svg canvas
let svg = d3.select(template.find(".chart"))
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// For each line 
data.forEach((item) => {

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(item.data, function(d) {
    if(d.value != undefined)
      return d.date;
  }));

  // Create a perfect looking domainrange to the nearest 10th
  y.domain([
    Math.floor(d3.min(item.data, function(d) {
      if(d.value != undefined)
        return d.value;
    })/10)*10
    ,
    Math.ceil(d3.max(item.data, function(d) {
      if(d.value != undefined)
        return d.value;
    })/10)*10

  ]);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Add only points that have value
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line color-"+ item.colorClass)
    .attr("d", valueline(item.data.filter((pnt) => pnt.value != undefined)));

});
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? :)

/Peter

UPDATE:

I found out it's like, that it want to show the new month. See this pen: http://codepen.io/DesignMonkey/pen/jbgYZx

It doesn't say "Septemper 1" but only "Septemper" like it wants to label the change of month. How do I disable this? :)

Comment: I think you'll need a custom format - [see docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#tickFormat)

Comment: Thanks... that pointed me the right way :)

Comment: Sure :) It's a good question, glad you found the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
var count = 0;
var tickRange = data[0].data.map((item) => {
  count = (count == 3) ? 0 : count+1;
  if(count == 1) {
   return item.date;
  }
})
.filter((d) => d != undefined);
```

and then:

```
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(d3.time.days, 3)
      .tickValues(tickRange)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%e'))
      .innerTickSize(-height)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(10)
```

Thanks :)